# Python SpeechRecognition having trouble processing short pronounced words

Tags: python, performance, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I have a project and I am using the SpeechRecognition module. I noticed that the recognizer have trouble processing input of short pronounced words like "next", "search", "write" and such. When i use these kind of words in a sentence like "Write something....", it doesn't have 'trouble' processing the mic input, i think its because it elongates the input/audio duration to a certain point. What I mean by 'trouble' is, when I say, for example "next", since it is short pronounced, The mic still waits for a while before closing and processing the input. The problem with this is that in my project most of the times, I only need to utter these words by itself, not in a sentence.

What I did to kind of work around this is I elongate pronouncing such words to meet that certain "audio duration". For example I pronounce the word 'next' to "neeeeeeeext" or the word 'search' "seeeeeaaarch". I don't want that because I sound stupid saying the commands that way. Any suggestions on how can I fix this? or am I just missing something? Thank you in advanced!

P/S. I use a separate recognizer/speechrecognizer tool, not the recognizers in the SpeechRecognizer module. I mainly use the SpeechRecognizer module for its mic and its features. I also don't use PyAudio because of latency issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide the parameters you are passing to the `recognize()` method. The method has parameters for how long to record for, how many seconds of audio to wait before recording etc. I believe the problem is with one of these settings.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide an exact answer to this question, but I recommend you use a HuggingFace model. You can try, for example, [whisper small](https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-small). In theory, the model is quite small and should run in your CPU without much delay.

Here is an example of how you would need to call it:

```py
# Use a pipeline as a high-level helper
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", model="openai/whisper-small")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I forgot to mention that the recognizer that I am using is the whisper base model, and i managed to access it purely offline (which is one of my goals in this project also) and it runs without issue. I am hesistant to use huggingface models because for me it lacks documentation and such and I am just a beginner when it comes to these stuff.